# Golang Use of array of structs that implement MyInterface as []MyInterface not allowed

Tags: go, interface

I can't use an array of structs that implement TheInterface as an argument for a method that receives []TheInterface.

I have the following scenario:

```
var earnings []Earning // where Earning implements the interface ValidableStep

for _, site := range sites {
  ... logic here
  earnings = append(earnings, siteEarning) // this works
}

# The below line produces this error: Cannot use 'earnings' (type []Earning) as the type []ValidableStep
validator.ValidateStep(earnings, "step 4")
```

where the definition of ValidateStep is

```
func ValidateStep(es []ValidableStep, customMsg string) {
...
}
```

Now I don't think I understand why this `validator.ValidateStep(earnings, "step 4")` is not allowed even though `Earning` is implementing `ValidableStep` so `[]Earning` should be an implementation of `[]ValidableStep`.

In any other programming language this would be trivial so I think I'm missing something in this case.

Comment: `[]Earning` is not an implementation of `[]ValidableStep`. Go types are invariant.

Comment: You're not missing anything. `[]Earning` is a slice type, it does not have any methods so cannot implement any non-empty interface, and it is a different type from `[]ValidableStep`, which is also a slice type and not an interface so nothing can implement it.